# Ruby on Rails Model Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new to Ruby on Rails.

I am trying to set up a relationship between a user model and a model of ten different items.

My goal is to have users be able to check off items in the items model and then have the ones that have been checked off display on their profile.

I have used the [Michael Hartl Ruby on Rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/) up to 
the point of creating microposts. 
Any tips on tutorials that will help me complete this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you want is:
A `User` `has_and_belongs_to_many :items`
Also, an `Item` `has_and_belongs_to_many :users`

This is **many to many** relationship. Since, a user can has many items, and an item can belong to many users too. In rails, here `has_and_belongs_to_many` will implicitly create a table `items_users` which will contain id's of both, establishing the relationship.

Read more about this association here - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association

Use `checkbox` tag for showing checkboxes for all the items. Documentation - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-check_box

Based on whatever checkboxes are checked, save the records, establishing the relationship.

Done. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about other tutorials, if you've completed Hatel's then you have a very very good understanding of the rails framework as a whole. I would have an items_list model. Which had a user_id foreign key to associate itself with a user. Then I could have an items model which had an items_list foreign key to associate them to a list. Then items model could have a boolean field "active" or "checked" or whatever. Using these, and the associated relations, and some scopes, you can get what you want.

Just make sure to use the includes helper when you request this data, otherwise you'll easily get a N+1 problem.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations